# Using @Inject in Dagger to use values from one module into another

Tags: java, dagger-2

I am relatively new to Dagger and I am trying to understand the usage of @Inject annotation between modules. Following is my code:

```
@Module
public class MyModule {

    @Provides
    @Named("myValue")
    @Singleton
    public String getRegion() {
        return System.getenv("myValue");
    }

}

@Module (includes = MyModule.class)
public class DependentModule {

    @Inject @Named("myValue") String myValue;

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public MyClass myclass() {
        return myClass.builder()
            .stringValue(myValue)
            .build();
    }
}


@Component
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    MyClass provideMyClass();
}
```

Code using the Dagger module :

```
ApplicationComponent APPLICATION_COMPONENT = DaggerApplicationComponent.create();

MyClass classInstance = APPLICATION_COMPONENT.provideMyClass();
```

Now each time I try to run my code, my program fails in the fact that the Injected value for the String seems to be always null. I've verified that the environment variable being returned isn't null (I did a manual system.getenv() call inside my main function and that returned a non null value)

I can't understand whether the Inject annotation isn't supposed to be used that way? Should I not be using the @Inject annotation and be using it as a method parameter?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Dagger specifically, but using `@Inject` (or equivalent annotations) on fields directly is discouraged because problems like this tend to arise frequently. Can you try using `@Inject` on a constructor instead and setting `myValue` there?

Comment: @chrylis: That didn't help. I still see the injected values to be null.

Comment: I am trying to also do the same. Is there solution that can be published here ?